# Add only new files using jgit

Tags: java, github, jgit

I am learning to push code to git using jgit. I am able to push all the files to git, but I only want to add new files or update the changes to git. Please suggest:

Below is my code:

```
Git git = Git.open(new File(repoPath)); // connect to github
// I want some code which recognizes the new additions or finds the files changed

git.add().addFilepattern(".").call(); // Want to add only the delta
git.commit().setMessage("commit - 1").call(); 
git.push().setCredentialsProvider(cp).call();
```

Comment: `git.add().addFilepattern(".").call()` adds new and changed files from the working directory to the index. Please tell us what you expect and what the actual outcome is.

Comment: git.add().addFilepattern(".").call() adds all the files. If we see the org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(){ boolean addAll = filepatterns.contains("."); } thus it adds all the files and not the delta. I need a parameter that can be passed to addFilepattern.

Answer (score 0):

Unchanged files are never added to the index, they are already contained in the index. Hence, use the file pattern `"."` if you want to add all new and changed files to the index.

The `addAll` variable you are referring to, is used to control whether to scan all files in the working directory or just the ones in the contained in the `filepatterns` list.

Answer (score 0):

```
//add files which have been modified or deleted
git.add().addFilepattern(".").setUpdate(true).call();
Status status = git.status().call();
//add new files
if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(status.getUntracked())) {
   AddCommand addCommand = git.add();
   for (String s : status.getUntracked()) {
        addCommand.addFilepattern(s);
   }
   addCommand.call();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Got it !!!

```
Status status = git.status().call();
System.out.println("Added: " + status.getAdded());
System.out.println("Changed: " + status.getChanged());
System.out.println("Conflicting: " + status.getConflicting());
System.out.println("ConflictingStageState: " + status.getConflictingStageState());
System.out.println("IgnoredNotInIndex: " + status.getIgnoredNotInIndex());
System.out.println("Missing: " + status.getMissing());
System.out.println("Modified: " + status.getModified());
System.out.println("Removed: " + status.getRemoved());
System.out.println("Untracked: " + status.getUntracked());
System.out.println("UntrackedFolders: " + status.getUntrackedFolders());
```